# will appear/appears/ is going to appear

Tags: word-choice, will-vs-going-to

Could anyone tell me the correct way of sneaking in a verb ''appear'' in the following sentence? The book is likely to be published and (will appear/appears/ is going to appear) on sale pretty soon.

Comment: I don't think you can really "sneak" the word ***appear*** in there if you're also going to have ***on sale***.  Using both looks clumsy and unnecessarily verbose to me. Either go for *and will appear soon* or *and will be on sale soon*. Using present tense (simple, or continuous ***is going to***) would be perfectly credible, but given your *precise* context (contrasting what is likely to be true *now* with what is expected to happen *later*) I think it's better to use the explicit future, but that's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: `and appear on sale` That's actually an infinitive which sort of borrows the elided `to` from `to be`. I certainly agree that `on sale` is redundant and wordy.

Answer (score 1):

All of those sentences would be grammatically correct, but it makes the sentence sound a little to wordy, a sentence like this would sound more to the point. (although not necessarily better)

> The book is likely to be published and will go on sale soon.

Though any of those sentences sound good, I would try to find the most precise and least wordy one for that scenario.